# What is the exact meaning of stride's list in tf.nn.conv2d?

Tags: tensorflow

```
conv2d( input, filter, strides, padding, use_cudnn_on_gpu=None, data_format=None, name=None)
strides=[b,h,w,c]
```

I know `b` means `batch`, `h` means `height`, `w` means `width` and `c` means `channel`. I see that `b` and `c` are always 1. What does it mean if `b = 2` or `c = 2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Stride` is the amount you want to skip in a particular direction. Each of your batch is 4 dimensional (`batch_size, height, width, channels`). But, you know that the computation should not skip any `batch` and nor should it skip any `channel`, but what a GPU sees is just a 4D tensor, and hence asks for the `stride` along each dimension.

`tf.nn.conv2d` is a low-level implementation in Tensorflow, which exposes the GPU API as it is. There is another high-level implementation as well, [`tf.layers.Conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/Conv2D) which only allows you to pass a two element tuple, with `height stride` and `width stride`. But, if you want to use the low-level API (maybe due to more control over the parameters), you should always keep batch and column stride to 1.